# how to parse a piece of info out of failureMessage string for generated result from a jest test suit run?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jest-image-snapshot

the string looks like this after I did JSON.stringify the whole object

`'Error: Expected image to match or be a close match to snapshot but was 0.009980258828690502% different from snapshot (91 differing pixels).\n\u001b[1m\u001b[31mSee diff for details:\u001b[39m\u001b[22m \u001b[31m/src/pages/__image_snapshots__/__diff_output__/register-test-js-register-page-register-automated-desktop-control-1-diff.png\u001b[39m\n    at Object.toMatchImageSnapshot (/src/command/getPageImageShot.js:62:25)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)'`

This value does not seems as a result of my json.stringify, as its the value within an object as a string by itself.

I wonder how can I parse out the whole path string (in this case its the path after `See diff for details` but without all the gibberish in between)  from this clumb of mess? and what process produced all the 39m, 22m, u0001b, etc? Is parsing it the best way? Maybe I overlooked some better approach?

I woonder

Comment: Depending on the consistency of the error messages, you can get the path either with splitting at ':', or regex. (among others)

Comment: @SimonL yea, I choose that approach as well... but was wonder if there is a "right" way to do it before .ha...